# Plotting confidence intervals from a dataframe

Tags: r, random, plot

I have written some R code which produces the limits of confidence intervals as well as the information if each confidence interval covers the true parameter. I'd like to visualize this but have no idea how.

```
confInt <- function(runs){
    result<-NULL
    vleft<-NULL
    vright<-NULL

    for (i in 1:runs) {
        data<-rnorm(1000)
        n<-length(data)
        a<-mean(data)
        s<-sd(data)
        error <- qnorm(0.975)*s/sqrt(n)
        left <- a-error
        right <- a+error

        result[i] = left<0 & 0<right
        vleft[i] = left 
        vright[i] = right
}
    data.frame(result,vleft,vright)
}


confInt(100)
```

[image: confidence]

EDIT: I have found a way using `ggplot2`

```
confInt <- function(runs){
    x<-1:runs
    mu<-NULL
    sigma<-NULL
    result<-NULL
    vleft<-NULL
    vright<-NULL

    for (i in 1:runs) {
        data<-rnorm(1000)
        n<-length(data)
        a<-mean(data)
        mu[i]<-a
        s<-sd(data)
        sigma[i]<-s
        error <- qnorm(0.975)*s/sqrt(n)
        left <- a-error
        right <- a+error

        result[i] = left<0 & 0<right
        vleft[i] = left 
        vright[i] = right
}
    data.frame(x,mu,sigma,result,vleft,vright)
}


df<-confInt(100)

require(ggplot2)

myplot<-ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = mu)) +
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = vleft, ymin = vright,colour=result*3))
myplot + theme_bw() 
summary(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this. Below, I use `mapply` to feed the the starting and ending points of each confidence interval to `segments`.

```
ci <- confInt(100)

plot(y = c(0, 100), x = c(-.15,.15), type = 'n', ylab = "",
    xlab = "", yaxt = 'n')

with(ci, mapply(segments, x0 = vleft, x1 = vright,
    y0 = 1:100, y1 = 1:100, col = (!result) + 1))

abline(v = 0, col = 'purple')
```

[image]